# Laravel 5 - How to show variable within view with escaped html?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$var_from_controller = "<div style="color:red">Picture inside html {{ asset('img/photo1.jpg') }} </div>"
```

@blade

```
<div id="my-container">
  {!! $var_from_controller !!}
</div>
```

It will render {{asset()}} as a string. But I need HTML **AND** asset() output.

How can I do this??

Comment: If you just want to show image then you can achieve it without asset helper, use absolute path of image within image tag.
Eg: `<img src="../assets/img/img_name.jpg" />`

Comment: @somsgod LOL. How da hell I missed this! I guess working marathon hours degrades basic brain functions:)) Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamental php here. You're trying to render a php variable while it's being parsed. It's to late to inject more php then.

You'll have to build your string before it's sent to php engine for rendering. (In mvc, before passing data to the view)

Comment: I would be very thankful if you could give an example. Because $var_from_controller pulls from db. Btw thx.

Comment: I get you. You have a problem with your asset funciton you forget about img tag <img src="../assets/img/photo1.jpg" /> . You are welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

In blade file change below code. concatenate image path in variable

```
@php
    $var_from_controller = "<div style='color:red'>Picture inside html ". asset('img/photo1.jpg') ." </div>";
@endphp

<div id="my-container">
   {!! $var_from_controller !!}
</div>
```